# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Issue with the **response.body().string()**
Searched all the post in the stackoverflow.
Cannot solve this issue.

```
 private void signIn() {
    Call<ResponseBody> call = ApiClient.getUserService().createUser(client_fullname, email, nationality, phone, dob, password, cpassword);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            System.out.println("The value of response is" + response.isSuccessful());

            ResponseBody result = response.body();
            try {
                myapiResult = result.string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

  
  if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                clearEditText();
                showAlertDialogBox("Sucessfully Submitted", "Thanks for believing us.", 1);
            }


          else if (myapiResult.equals(email)) {
                showAlertDialogBox("Error", "Already Registered.Please Login", 1);

            }
```

Comment: Your response.body() is returning null. Looks like API call is Unsuccessful.
Check the API response, and share the Logcat of this call if possible

Comment: @Samin yes u are right, the logcat  error is::D/OkHttp: {"status":false,"message":"Email already exists"}
    <-- END HTTP (49-byte body)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: soanitech.n.travelApp, PID: 12800
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference
        at soanitech.n.travel.SignUpActivity$4.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:339)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is null first check it to avoid crash.

```
if(response.body() != null) {
        String s = response.body().string();
    }
```

Then you need to send proper response from back end to avoid body to be null.